# Google Apps Script limitations

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization

I am trying to use Google Apps Script together with Google Sheets to get API data from a bank to my online table, but looks it is absolutely impossible. Every time I do it, I get these messages:

"Authorization required
Exchange Rate Table needs your permission to access your data on Google
Google sign-in is temporarily disabled for this application
This app has not yet been verified for Google Sign-in".

What kind of authorization Google needs again? I tried to learn at the Google Identity Platform, but found there 10 page instructions with a lot of useful hyperlinks. I need a university course at least to understand it.

Comment: What is "Exchange Rate Table"?

Comment: Hey there @Oleg, your issue looks like this one [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820). Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes @ale13 it looks like I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a known issue regarding Apps Script.**

I suggest you star the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145162820) and eventually add a comment saying that you are affected by it.